# simple JOIN query which doesnt work

Tags: mysql, join

Im learning SQL and could someone tell me what is wrong with the query?

```
SELECT * FROM customers AS C
Inner Join customers AS CC
on CC.City=C.City
INNER JOIN customers AS CCC
ON
CCC.City=C.City
```

Im using "virtual database" with MYSQL for query testing.

Comment: What is the error that you get? What is the expected output?

Comment: THe error is Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CC.City=C.City INNER JOIN customers AS CCC ON CCC.City=C.City'. I dont expectany output - im learning how to combine many JOINS

Comment: I'm not really familiar with MySql, but try removing the AS's from your query i.e. just customers c, customers cc etc?

Comment: Doesnt work. I think the site im testing it on is wrong.

Comment: What is this *"virtual database"* ? The query looks valid (although not very useful).

Comment: Try running it with `SELECT C.*, CC.*, CCC.* ...` or with `SELECT C.* ...`, as @Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like:

```
SELECT C.* FROM customers C 
Inner Join customers CC 
on CC.City=C.City 
INNER JOIN 
customers CCC ON CCC.City=C.City
```